# Add two rows in a query but leave all others as they are

Tags: sql-server

If I have a query like

```
SELECT A, SUM(B)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
GROUP BY A
```

However there are two values of `A` that I want to sum in the result. So lets say `A` holds currency codes e.g:

```
'USD'
'USD big'
'EUR'
'GBP'
'JPY'
etc...
```

Now I want to sum the result of `SUM(B)` for every currency EXCEPT when `A` is `"USD"` or `"USD big"`, then I want to add them together and multiply the result of the `"USB big"` row by 100.

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Just to further explain, let's say the result of my query is currently:

```
A       | SUM(B)
------------
USD     | 1000
USD big | 2
EUR     | 50
GBP     | 26
JPY     | 5
```

I would like to alter my query such that it instead returns:

```
A       | SUM(B)
------------
USD     | 1200      -- i.e. 1000 + 2*100
EUR     | 50
GBP     | 26
JPY     | 5
```

Where that `1200` is the `1000` from the `USD` row plus 100 time the `2` from the `USD big` row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use approach like this one:

```
select
    T.A, sum(T.B)
from
    (
        select
            case when A = 'USD big' then 'USD' else A end as A,
            case when A = 'USD big' then B * 100 else B end as B
        from MyTable
        where ...
    ) as T
group by T.A
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest approach is probably a union of 2 select statements, one

```
where CurrencyCode not in ('USD', 'USD big')
```

and the other

```
'where CurrencyCode in ('USD', 'USD big')'
```

or to do it via a single statement, something like the following should do the trick

```
 select CurrCode, Sum(CurrAmount)
 from (
        select case CurrencyCode   
                  when 'USD' then 'USD big'
                       else CurrencyCode
               end as CurrCode,
               case CurrencyCode
                  when 'USD big' then B* 100
                  else B      
               as CurrAmount
          from tableA
      ) T
group by CurrCode
```

**Edit:** Just spotted your * 100 requirement. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks, I went with Andy's approach which is the same as your second approach.